# pandas: vectorize counting rows in time interval

Tags: python, pandas

My situation is as follows. I've got one Series (`a_series`) of events of type A, indexed by PersonID and another ID irrelevant to the question:

```
PersonID      AnotherID
19            768           2013-02-03 13:39:00
              767           2013-02-03 14:03:00
              766           2013-02-03 15:35:00
              765           2013-02-03 22:32:00
              764           2013-02-04 11:36:00
              763           2013-02-04 12:07:00
26            762           2013-02-18 13:21:00
...
730           66901         2014-08-21 21:09:00
              67078         2014-08-22 23:44:00
              67141         2014-08-23 11:16:00
              67168         2014-08-23 14:53:00
              67216         2014-08-23 21:45:00
Name: Timestamp, Length: 34175, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And I've got another Series (`b_series`), built exactly the same, but describing events of type B:

```
PersonID      AnotherID
26            939       2013-02-18 06:01:00
              940       2013-02-18 06:47:00
              941       2013-02-19 07:02:00
...
728           65159     2014-08-14 18:40:00
729           66104     2014-08-18 09:08:00
              66229     2014-08-18 17:31:00
Name: Timestamp, Length: 1886, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note that while the structure is the same, the index is not the same  - meaning that a person might have more events A than event B, and might not have events of a certain type at all.

I want to create a series with the same structure of `a_series`, but for each row, counting the number of events from b_series which happened up to 12 hours before the A event. So for example, if we take the line `26            762           2013-02-18 13:21:00` from `series_a`, it's value should be 2.

I've managed to do this with apply, like this:

```
def apply_func(x, series_b):
    try:
        return series_b.loc[x['PersonID']].\
            between(x['Timestamp'] - timedelta(hours = 12), x['Timestamp']).sum()
    except KeyError:
        return 0

new_series = series_a.apply(apply_func, axis = 1, args = (seriesb,))
new_series.index = series_a.index
```

But I can't help but feel there has to be a more efficient, "panda-ic" way. Perhaps with groupby, or lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of frame and number of matches it *may* be more efficient to use join operations:

First, give the series names and change them to data-frames:

```
>>> a.name, b.name = 'a', 'b'
>>> xb = b.reset_index(level=-1).filter('b')
>>> xa = a.reset_index()
```

Then, join them on `'PersonID'`:

```
>>> df = xa.join(xb, on='PersonID', how='inner')
>>> df
   PersonID  AnotherID                   a                   b
6        26        762 2013-02-18 13:21:00 2013-02-18 06:01:00
6        26        762 2013-02-18 13:21:00 2013-02-18 06:47:00
6        26        762 2013-02-18 13:21:00 2013-02-19 07:02:00
```

Now, count the number of hits:

```
>>> lag = np.timedelta64(12, 'h')
>>> df['cnt'] = (df['b'] < df['a']) & (df['a'] < df['b'] + lag)
>>> ts = df.groupby(['PersonID', 'AnotherID', 'a'])['cnt'].sum()
>>> ts
PersonID  AnotherID  a                  
26        762        2013-02-18 13:21:00    2
Name: cnt, dtype: float64
```

and, align with the original series:

```
>>> xcol = ['PersonID', 'AnotherID', 'a']
>>> xa.join(ts, on=xcol).fillna(0).set_index(xcol[:-1])
                                     a  cnt
PersonID AnotherID                         
19       768       2013-02-03 13:39:00    0
         767       2013-02-03 14:03:00    0
         766       2013-02-03 15:35:00    0
         765       2013-02-03 22:32:00    0
         764       2013-02-04 11:36:00    0
         763       2013-02-04 12:07:00    0
26       762       2013-02-18 13:21:00    2
730      66901     2014-08-21 21:09:00    0
         67078     2014-08-22 23:44:00    0
         67141     2014-08-23 11:16:00    0
         67168     2014-08-23 14:53:00    0
         67216     2014-08-23 21:45:00    0
```

Comment: The first join is actually a Cartesian product, right? I'll try to time this on real data. Thanks.

Comment: @Korem it is Cartesian product only per matching `PersonID` rows, not the two frames. It is still a bottleneck for above code, and may not be efficient if there are many rows per `PersonID` in both series.

Comment: Yes, but my solution isn't any better in those terms. It traverses the exact same number of "rows".